# What is the difference between following code

Tags: asp.net, gridview, datakey

```
var id = Convert.ToInt32(GridViewVehicleList.DataKeys[e.NewSelectedIndex].Value);
var id2 = Convert.ToInt32(GridViewVehicleList.DataKeys[e.NewSelectedIndex].Values);
```

if i use second code as

```
id2 = Convert.ToInt32(GridViewVehicleList.DataKeys[e.NewSelectedIndex].Values[1]);
```

, could i assign second DataKey to variable id2

Thanks for all interests

Comment: Read [Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datakey_properties(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: yes, you can.you are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DataKey Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datakey_properties%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Value

```
Gets the value of the key field at index 0 in the DataKey object.
```

Values

```
Gets an IOrderedDictionary object that contains every key field in the DataKey 
object.
```

---

So you can assign

```
id2 = Convert.ToInt32(GridViewVehicleList.DataKeys[e.NewSelectedIndex].Values[1]);
```